# deploy xml files during install of visual studio lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have several files that i would like to copy to a specific directory on a target client when i install my two tier lightswitch application.  I thought it should be as simple as adding the files to the client or server side project and marking the file properties 'Copy always' in Copy to Output Directory field.  When i compile, publish and install, the files aren't anywhere to be found.  I've tried moving the files around on the source side within my client and server projects, but haven't had much luck.  One time i was able to get it to install the files but they were buried inside of a Datasource directory deep in the targets filestructure.  Is this basic functionality that i'm just not configuring properly or is it a bigger issue?

Comment: it is possible that group policy on my target is somehow wiping certain files it deems bad.  I'm going to try this out on a target that isn't locked down.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your Package Action is set to Content, then set the copy behaviour you want. You can find these settings in the Properties window when you select the file in the Solution Explorer.

Do a rebuild and confirm that they show up in the correct place in the project configuration directory (debug or release), then check they show up in the correct place when you publish.